# Is there a package for Bayesian Linear Regression?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, packages

Is there a Mathematica package for Bayesian linear regression?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a lot around:

See [Bayesian Statistics and Econometrics using Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6900/)

http://library.wolfram.com/search/?query=Bayesian&collection=library&x=0&y=0

[Google mathematica Bayesian](https://www.google.ch/search?q=mathematica+basian&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XU4BV-XOCsT-Uu7PiagO#q=mathematica+Bayesian)

Comment: Many thanks Louis ;)

Answer (score 9):

I am a bit late, but here is a short paper of mine with Wolfram Language code. It covers Bayesian regression as well as model selection. Take notice of the books in the references. Excellent for self study.  http://djafari.free.fr/MaxEnt2014/papers/04_paper.pdf

Answer (score 6):

For some reason this question didn't come up when I tried searching for it before, so I ended up creating a new question for it and answering it myself.

[How to fit a linear model in the Bayesian way in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202065/how-to-fit-a-linear-model-in-the-bayesian-way-in-mathematica)

In this answer I provide a link to my Bayesian inference repository which has a function that's the Bayesian equivalent of Mathematica's `LinearModelFit`.