# How to fit a linear model in the Bayesian way in Mathematica?

Tags: fitting, linear-algebra, probability-or-statistics

Basically, I'm looking for the Bayesian equivalent of `LinearModelFit`. As of the moment of writing, Mathematica has no real (documented) built-in 
functionality for Bayesian fitting of data, but for linear regression there exist closed-form solutions for the posterior coefficient distributions and the posterior predictive distributions. Have these been implemented somewhere?

Comment: It might be of interest to look at the option  FitRegularization in FindFit

Comment: @chris I'm aware of the new fit regularization options. In particular, fitting with L2 regularization can be considered as an approximation to a MAP estimate with the appropriate priors. `BayesianLinearRegression` is meant to implement the full Bayesian treatment, not an approximation.

Comment: OK I am not trying to lower the interest of what you did. I believe  MAP  falls within the Bayesian framework. If I use say a Gaussian prior, the MAP give an exact  solution, not an approximation. I guess this is just semantics though.

Comment: @chris It depends on what you call "the solution". I you ask me, the "solution" in a Bayesian setting is always a distribution, not a value or point estimate. A MAP estimate is a reduction of said distribution to a single value, which amounts to throwing away information. However, if you want to make a MAP estimate using my code, that's easy: all of the distributions are there. Just reduce them to numbers any way you want. Mean, median, mode: your choice.

Comment: For Gaussian noise with a Gaussian prior, the MAP solution is a description of the Gaussian posterior, which is an exhaustive description of the corresponding  Distribution. In any case I think people reading your post would also be interested in knowing that Mathematica  now has `FitRegularization` now built in. The rest is linguistics IMHO.

Comment: Fair enough. Just to be clear though: my model also has a prior over the variance and the prior/posterior distributions over the fit variables is not Gaussian but a conditional product of an inverse gamma and Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I submitted this question to answer it myself, since I recently updated my [Bayesian inference repository on GitHub](https://github.com/ssmit1986/BayesianInference) with a function called `BayesianLinearRegression` that does just this.  I wrote a general introduction to its functionalities on the [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1736686) and [Wolfram Blog](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/08/22/embracing-uncertainty-better-model-selection-with-bayesian-linear-regression/) and the [example notebook on GitHub](https://github.com/ssmit1986/BayesianInference/blob/master/example_code.nb) shows some more advanced uses of the function. I also submitted the function to the [Wolfram function repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) and you can use this version simply by evaluating:

```
BayesianLinearRegression = ResourceFunction["BayesianLinearRegression", "Function"];
```

Please refer to the README.md file (shown on the front page of the repository link) for instructions on the installation of the `BayesianInference` package. If you don't want the whole package, you can also get the code for `BayesianLinearRegression` directly from the [relevant package file](https://github.com/ssmit1986/BayesianInference/blob/release_v1.1/BayesianInference/BayesianLinearRegression.wl).

### Example of use

`BayesianLinearRegression` uses the same syntax as `LinearModelFit`. In addition, it also supports `Rule`-based definitions of input-output data as used by `Predict` (i.e., data of the form `{x1 -> y1, ...}` or `{x1, x2, ...} -> {y1, y2, ...}`). This format is particularly useful for multivariate regression (i.e., when the `y` values are vectors), which is also supported by `BayesianLinearRegression`.

The output of the function is an `Association` with all relevant information about the fit.

```
data = {
  {-1.5`,-1.375`},{-1.34375`,-2.375`},{1.5`,0.21875`}, {1.03125`,0.6875`},{-0.5`,-0.59375`},  {-1.875`,-2.59375`},{1.625`,1.1875`},
  {-2.0625`,-1.875`},{1.0625`,0.5`},{-0.4375`,-0.28125`},{-0.75`,-0.75`},{2.125`,0.375`},{0.4375`,0.6875`},{-1.3125`,-0.75`},{-1.125`,-0.21875`},
  {0.625`,0.40625`},{-0.25`,0.59375`},{-1.875`,-1.625`},{-1.`,-0.8125`},{0.4375`,-0.09375`}
};
Clear[x];
model = BayesianLinearRegression[data, {1, x}, x];
Keys[model]
```

> Out[21]= {"LogEvidence", "PriorParameters", "PosteriorParameters", "Posterior", "Prior", "Basis", "IndependentVariables"}

The [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) is specified as an `x`-dependent probability distribution:

```
model["Posterior", "PredictiveDistribution"]
```

> Out[15]= StudentTDistribution[-0.248878 + 0.714688 x, 0.555877 Sqrt[1.05211 + 0.0164952 x + 0.031814 x^2], 2001/100]

Show the single prediction bands:

```
With[{
  predictiveDist = model["Posterior", "PredictiveDistribution"],
  bands = {95, 50, 5}
  },
 Show[
  Plot[
   Evaluate@InverseCDF[predictiveDist, bands/100],
   {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {2}}, PlotLegends -> bands
   ],
  ListPlot[data],
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Prediction bands of 1st degree fit]

It looks like the data could also be fitted with a quadratic fit. To test this, compute the log-evidence for polynomial models up to degree 4 and rank them:

```
In[152]:= models = AssociationMap[
   BayesianLinearRegression[Rule @@@ data, x^Range[0, #], x] &,
   Range[0, 4]
   ];
ReverseSort @ models[[All, "LogEvidence"]]
```

> Out[153]= <|1 -> -30.0072, 2 -> -30.1774, 3 -> -34.4292, 4 -> -38.7037, 0 -> -38.787|>

The evidences for the first and second degree models are almost equal. In this case, it may be more appropriate to define a mixture of the models with weights derived from their evidences:

```
 weights = Normalize[
   (* subtract the max to reduce rounding error *)
   Exp[models[[All, "LogEvidence"]] - Max[models[[All, "LogEvidence"]]]],
   Total
   ];
 mixDist = MixtureDistribution[
   Values[weights],
   Values @ models[[All, "Posterior", "PredictiveDistribution"]]
   ];
Show[
 (*regressionPlot1D is a utility function from the package*)
 regressionPlot1D[mixDist, {x, -3, 3}], 
 ListPlot[data]
 ]
```

[image: Prediction bands of a mixture model of polynomials up to degree 4]

As you can see, the mixture model shows features of both the first and second degree fits to the data.

Please refer to the example notebook for information about specification of priors (see the section "Options of BayesianLinearRegression" -> "PriorParameters") and multivariate regression.

### Detailed explanation about the returned values

For purposes of illustration, consider a simple model like:

```
y == a + b x + eps
```

with `eps` distributed as `NormalDistribution[0, sigma]`. This model is fitted with `BayesianLinearRegression[data, {1, x}, x]`. Here is an explanation of the keys in the returned `Association`:

- "LogEvidence": In a Bayesian setting, the evidence (also called
  [marginal likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood)) measures how well the model fits the data (with
  a higher evidence indicating a better fit). The evidence has the
  virtue that it naturally penalizes models for their complexity and
  therefore does not suffer from over-fitting in the way that measures
  like the sum-of-squares or (log-)likelihood do.
- "Basis", "IndependentVariables": Simply the basis functions and independent variable specified by the user.
- "Posterior", "Prior": These two keys each hold an association with 4 distributions:

1. "PredictiveDistribution": A distribution that depends on the
   independent variables (`x` in the example above). By filling in a value
   for `x`, you get a distribution that tells you where you could expect
   to find future `y` values. This distribution accounts for all relevant
   uncertainties in the model: model variance caused by the term
   `eps`; uncertainty in the values of `a` and `b`; and uncertainty in
   `sigma`.
2. "UnderlyingValueDistribution": Similar to "PredictiveDistribution", but this distribution gives the possible values of `a + b x` without the `eps` error term.
3. "RegressionCoefficientDistribution": The joint distribution over `a` and `b`.
4. "ErrorDistribution": The distribution of the variance `sigma^2`.

- "PriorParameters", "PosteriorParameters": These parameters are not immediately important most of the time, but they contain all of the relevant information about the fit.

People familiar with Bayesian analysis may note that one distribution is absent: the full joint distribution over `a`, `b` and `sigma` together (I only gave the marginals over `a` and `b` on one hand and `sigma` on the other). This is because Mathematica doesn't really offer a convenient framework for representing this distribution, unfortunately.

### Sources of formulas used:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_multivariate_linear_regression

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to set the prior? What prior did you use by default?

Comment: @Roman Yes you can: "Please refer to the example notebook for information about specification of priors" ;) (I updated that sentence with the section where you can find it)

Comment: Nice. I believe version 12 provides penalty in all fitting routines of mathematica? This is equivalent to maximum a posteriori where exp(penalty) represents the prior?

Comment: @chris Functions like `LinearModelFit` compute the Akaike Information Criterion and Bayesian Information Criterion. The serve a similar purpose, but are quite different from the Bayesian evidence. Furthermore, `BayesianLinearRegression` does not make point estimates (such as MAP) but retains the full distribution over the fit coefficients. Don't throw away information if you don't have to ;).

Comment: Really cool stuff

Comment: Thank you for doing this work and sharing it with the community.  I do find it frustrating that Wolfram has not made greater efforts to facilitate the use the Bayesian paradigm and statistical models for those users, such as myself, who are not capable of building/programming these models/implementations themselves; but nonetheless are able and desirous of following along with the  competent and professional implementations of others.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, thank you!!!  Any  thoughts on how much additional effort it would take to  extend it to quantile regression ( [Bayesian Quantile Regression](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i07)))?

Comment: @kglr I have never seen that before, but a cursory glance at that source suggest that there is no conjugate prior for that type of regression. Is that correct? It seems like a rather different method to me. At any rate, I just released an update to my GitHub code and included a function for doing Laplace approximations for inference problems. You could try to use that if you want a different error model than Gaussian errors.